# How to find all possible combinations of a matrix with fixed components

Tags: matlab

Given a 3by2 matrix with constant values

```
B = [b1 b1;b2 b2;b3 b3]
```

I need to make a code that would use the initial B matrix and place zeros progressively to any place of its current components. This means that we need factorial(6) combinations.
The first combination which would be of no use, is when we replace all components with 6 zeros:

```
B_0 = [0 0;0 0;0 0]
```

The first useful output would be, placing 5 zeros in all places BUT the (1,1)

```
B_1 = [b1 0;0 0;0 0]
```

The second, would be placing zeros in all places but the (2,1):

```
B_2 = [0 0;b1 0;0 0]
```

so on for the third:

```
B_3 = [0 0;0 0;b1 0]
```

After finishing with placing all the combinations for 5 zeros, we start to add 4 zeros:

```
B_k = [b1 0;b2 0;0 0]
B_k+1 = [b1 0;0 0;b3 0]
```

etc.
and then 3 zeros

```
B_n = [b1 0;b2 0;b3 0]
B_n+1 = [b1 0;b2 0;0 b3]
```

etc.

Until, we arrive to the last case of no zeros to be replaced which brings us to the initial matrix

```
B_6! = [b1 b1;b2 b2;b3 b3]
```

Comment: This looks extremely similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57674419/how-can-i-build-a-matrix-which-includes-all-possible-combinations) which was just closed as unclear. Given that this account is brand new, did you just create it to re-ask the same question in a different guise? Regardless, please read the comments under that question to see why this is unclear, [edit] your question to include a [mcve], and show a *complete* example.

Comment: I just made my first account on this domain of stackoverflow. I didn't post the question you are referring to. Personally, being not a specialist on the field, I find no similarity between the two questions, but i will gladly edit mine to make it more clear.

Comment: Both questions are using `nchoosek` to find all combinations between a given array and an array of zeros, no? Either way, please provide a [mcve] as requested, it will make the question easier to answer. Think to yourself, anywhere you've put `...` and think something is obvious, we are in the dark and have no idea what you expect to fill the space, unless clearly mathematically defined.

Comment: For me each element can be `0` or the original element, so there is 2^6 = 64 combinations. There will be `6!`combinations only if the order of the 0 element matters, which don't seems to be the case according to your example, am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the assumption that there is a mistake in your question (according to my comment). So there is only 2^6 = 64 possible combinations.

In this case you can use:

```
m        = 6                           %vector length
[y{1:m}] = ndgrid(0:1);                %all combination of 0 and 1 with m possible permutations
y        = reshape(cat(m+1,y{:}),[],m);
res      = y.*[1 1 2 2 3 3]            %get the result

%reshape and permute
res = permute(reshape(res.',2,3,64),[2,1,3])
```

I've added a new dimension instead of creating 64 new variables (which is not the way to go).

**result** (before adding a new dimension and reshaping):

```
res =

   0   0   0   0   0   0
   1   0   0   0   0   0
   0   1   0   0   0   0
   1   1   0   0   0   0
   0   0   2   0   0   0
   1   0   2   0   0   0
   0   1   2   0   0   0
   1   1   2   0   0   0
   0   0   0   2   0   0
   ...
```